# Toggl API with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, http, rest

Having tried to access the Toggl reporting API with PHP cURL, I've had no luck and now trying HTTPRequest with JavaScript. I'm receiving a 200 response from the API so know I'm connected, I'm just at a loss at what to do next.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://toggl.com/reports/api/v2", false);
xhr.send();
document.write("Status code: " + xhr.status + " ");
document.write(xhr.statusText + "</br>");
```

I tried setting a request header as described in the documentation but this kills the 200 response, so I know I'm doing it wrong...

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization':'[api token encoded with base 64]','Content-type':'application/json');
```

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a couple of years late, but in case anyone is in the same position, this works for me:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://toggl.com/reports/api/v2/weekly?user_agent=yourname@domain.com&workspace_id=012345", false);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic XXXXXX');
xhr.send();
document.write("Status code: " + xhr.status + " ");
document.write(xhr.statusText + "</br>");
```

Where XXXXXX is your api key plus the string ":api_token" encoded in base-64.

So if your api key is 12345, you encode the string "12345:api_token" in base-64 to get MTIzNDU6YXBpX3Rva2Vu.

In javascript you can use the btoa function to get the base-64 encoded string: btoa("12345:api_token").

**NB**: Note that in the URL you need to specify **user_agent** and **workspace_id**, as stated in the toggle api documentation: https://github.com/toggl/toggl_api_docs/blob/master/reports.md

The easiest way to find the workspace_id is to click on the tab called "Team" and copy the number from the URL: https://toggl.com/app/team/***012345***

user_agent is the name of your application or your email address.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any API that has you use : in the headers for JS, try replacing them with ,

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','[api token encoded with base 64]','Content-type','application/json');
```